# Replace Column in Data Frame from Lookup of other Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi, I have two data frames, one containing:-

```
<p>Country Code | Population </p>
```

and another containing:-

```
<p>Country Code | Country Name. </p>
```

I want to do a replace in the first data frame so that CountryCode = CountryName where applicable. Important to note if the lookup failed, i.e. no CountryCode matched in second data frame I would like to keep as is. Any ideas how this can be done?

Sample:-

```
<p>Country Code | Population </p>
<p>RSA | 100</p>
<p>POL | 50</p>

<p> Country Code | Country Name </p>
<p> RSA | South Africa </p>
```

Expected Output for DF1

```
<p> Country Code | Population </p>
<p> South Africa | 100 </p>
<p> POL | 50 </p>
```

Comment: can you give us the input and the expected output?

Comment: Only one answer should be acepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your 2 dataframes are `df1` and `df2` respectively, this is one way:

```
s = df2.set_index('Country Code')['Country Name']
df1['Country Code'] = df1['Country Code'].map(s).fillna(df1['Country Code'])
```

This is also possible via `replace`, but `map` + `fillna` is generally more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) by `Series` created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
s = DF2.set_index('Country Code')['Country Name']
DF1['Country Code'] = DF1['Country Code'].replace(s)
print (DF1)
   Country Code  Population
0  South Africa         100
1           POL          50
```